# uibutton on top of image view not aligning

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton, size-classes

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UIImageView`, and I put a `UIButton` on top of the `UIImageView`.

I am using size classes (width compact, high regular, all iphones portrait).

When I add constraints to the `button`, it changes positions on different iPhone screens.

I have checked a lot of size class tutorials, but all of them are like putting button in the centre, or adding multiple buttons then evenly spread out.

Do anyone know any tutorial like adding only one button to the screen, and the button remains at the same position according to the background image?

Settings:

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko2Q6.png)

[Storyboard at design time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yTIP.png)

TBC

Comment: Share the code you have with us, if possible keep it compact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **Use Size Classes** and **Use AutoLayout** and then change the view gaps from the column next to attributes inspector

[image]

This way you can have constraints and same location on all  devices